# How to disable omnifunc autowrite suggestions

Tags: go, vim, vim-go

I am new to vim and I installed vim-go today. I set up auto completion with gopls with omnifunc set as `go#complete#Complete`. It works as expected but it always writes the current suggestion automatically. this is very annoying since it always writes the suggestion without me accepting it.

Comment: "I am new to vim and I installed vim-go today." As a new user, you have much more useful things to do than installing plugins. Does insert mode completion work as expected in a non-go buffer? If yes, then you should use the plugin's issue tracker because your problem has nothing to do with Vim.

Comment: It was my mistake to assume the problem was with vim-go. I didn't know the completion was a vim feature not of vim-go. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the problem was the default value of `completeopt` option in vim. editing it to have the value `noinsert` solved the problem. add the following line in ~/.vimrc
`set completeopt=menuone,popup,noinsert`
The above is just an example. the values except `noinsert` are just my own preferences.